# EMR not generating step logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, logging, amazon-emr

Due to some reason, I do not see steps logs for my jobs in EMR. It used to work fine a while back, but it just stopped logging.
I checked from HDFS in path  /mnt/var/log/hadoop/steps/, but there is no log there. The steps do complete successfully, just that there are no logs.
Is there anything I can do to find the issue and get the logger back to work?

### Thanks in advance for taking time to read and respond.
All the best.